# How would I capture the 'alt' attribute for the images a user selects from this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key-value, alt

How can I modify this script to capture the 'alt' attribute for the images a user selects in a slideshow?

This code displays a series of 20 pairs of images and asks users to select their preferences. Each time the user clicks one of the 'Select' buttons, the 'manipulateDOM()' function advances to the next set of items in the the text and image arrays. However, since it's not set up as a typical form field, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to capture the value of each selection so that it can be submitted to the database with the rest of the form values.

I tried creating a function with the click() method to (at the very least) capture the src value, but I can't get the syntax right so that it can run in conjunction with the 'manipulateDOM()' function. I'd also much rather capture the 'alt' attribute, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

**Function I was experimenting with:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#buttons").click(function () {           
         var imgvalue = $("#imgtrendy").attr("src");
         $("#picval").text(imgvalue);
         document.write(imgvalue + ', ');
     });
 });
```

**Existing Code:**

**Javascript - manipulateDOM() and manipulateDOM1() functions**

```
 var NumberOfImages = 3 - 1; //-1 because array members starts from 0
 var trendy = new Array(NumberOfImages);
 trendy[0] = "files/set1/A1.jpg"; 
 trendy[1] = "files/set1/B1.jpg"; 
 trendy[2] = "files/set1/C1.jpg";
 var imgNumber = 1; //array key of current image

 var NumberOfImages = 3 - 1;
 var classic = new Array(NumberOfImages);
 classic[0] = "files/set1/A2.png"; 
 classic[1] = "files/set1/B2.jpg"; 
 classic[2] = "files/set1/C2.jpg";
 var classicNumber = 1;

 var text = 3 - 1;
 var text = new Array;
 text[0] = "Which would you be more likely to wear?"
 text[1] = "Which look is more you?"
 text[2] = "Which would you rather wear?"
 var textNumber = 1;   

function manipulateDOM() {
     changeObjects();
     NextImage();
 }
 function changeObjects() {
     document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text[textNumber];     
 }   
 function NextImage() {
     if (imgNumber < NumberOfImages) //Stop moving forward when we are out of images
     {
         imgNumber++;
         document.images["taste"].src = trendy[imgNumber];
         document.images["taste1"].src = classic[imgNumber];
         textNumber++;  
         document.getElementById["question"].innerHTML = text[textNumber];
         document.getElementById["selectButton"].innerHTML = text[textNumber];
     }   
 }    
 function manipulateDOM1() {
     changeObjects();
     NextImage1();
 }
 function NextImage1() {
     if (imgNumber < NumberOfImages)
     {
         imgNumber++;
         document.images["taste"].src = trendy[imgNumber];
         document.images["taste1"].src = classic[imgNumber];
         textNumber++;  
         document.getElementById["question"].innerHTML = text[textNumber];
         document.getElementById["selectButton"].innerHTML = text[textNumber];
     } 
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="taste" name="taste" method="post" action="taste-exec.php" >
<h2 id="question"> Which would you be more likely to wear?</h2>
<table><tr>
   <td><img id="imgtrendy" src="files/set1/A1.jpg" name="taste" value="trendy[1]" /></td>
   <td><img id="imgclassic" src="files/set1/A2.png" name="taste1" value="classic[1]"  /></td></tr>
<tr id="buttons">
   <td><img id="trendyButton" alt"Select" src="files/Select.jpg" onclick="javascript:manipulateDOM()"></td>
   <td ><img id="classicButton" alt"Select" src="files/Select.jpg" onclick="javascript:manipulateDOM1()"></td> 
</tr><tr>
   <td id="picval"></td>
   <td><input name="answer" id="answer" type="text" /></td>
</tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: You already have the answer in your code from where you set the image src - `document.images["taste"].src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the alt attribute using also the `attr` method and `alt` as parameter, just like you are already doing with `src`. You could try:

```
 function changeObjects() {
     document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text[textNumber];     

     var imgvalue = $("#imgtrendy").attr("alt");
     $("#picval").text(imgvalue);
 }
```

**Edit: Example of keeping  data in one single array**

```
//to save it
var alt = $("#imgtrendy").attr("alt");
var fileName= 'someValue';//populate accordingly
var myArray[index] = alt + '|' + fileName;
//to retrieve it
var bothValues = myArray[index].split('|'); //gives you an array
alt = bothValues[0] //contains alt at index 0
fileName = bothValues[1] //contains fileName at index 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was almost there, but I couldn't quite figure it out :-) One question - what's the correct format for adding the alt attribute to the array? The only method I've seen wasn't working with my code -  '<img src="files/set1/A1.jpg" alt="trendy_jeans">'

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! regarding your question, what array? the alt value can be added as any other value to an array, for example `myArray[i] = imgvalue`

Comment: The arrays were at the bottom and were easy to overlook if you didn't keep scrolling, so I just moved them to the top of the JS ;-) In the full code there are 10 arrays with 20 images in each array

Comment: Since I need to include both the file name and the alt attribute in the image value, I'm not quite sure how to format it :-( Would you mind showing me an example with one of the items in my array?

Comment: This may be better suited for a new question but my preference would be to create separate arrays (one for the file names and for the alt attributes). If you really want only one array you could concatenate the values using pipe (|) for example and then just splitting them using `myArray[index].split('|')`

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure it out! I'd rather keep it in one array (much easier to maintain), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to concatenate it properly (and the research I did just highlighted what a beginner I am). I tried comma separating it, as well as  trendy[0].split('|') = '<img src=" files/set1/A1.jpg" alt="trendy_jeans">'; Would you mind showing me how to format it, or it that's too complicated can you show me how I would use the function with 2 separate arrays for each image (I haven't seen that before)?

Comment: I'd love it if you could help me with the syntax so that I can try out your beautiful solution, but if you think it's better suited to a new question I'd be happy to post it separately :-)

Comment: I didn't work because you were separating it with commas and splitting with pipes, you gotta use the same char. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that :-) What I meant though is that the slideshow stopped working with the way that I tried adding the 'alt' attribute to the array. Would you mind adding one sample field to your example so that I understand how to structure the array with the alt attribute?

Comment: That's what I did with the `myArray` example. If the slideshow stopped maybe you have a syntax issue.

Comment: lol - I meant that the slideshow stopped with what I'd tried earlier :-) I'm not following how to set up the array though with the myArray example :-( Would you mind showing me how to do it with one of the items in 'var trendy'?

Comment: That example should shed some light on this but you may need to start a new question regarding arrays manipulation.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit stupid, but I've spent the past hour trying to figure out how to insert the file name and alt attribute correctly :-( Am I correct in understanding that this is for separate arrays (one for file names and one for alt attributes), and 'var fileName' replaces 'var trendy' (in a slightly different format)? If so, can you point out which one should be populated with the 'alt' attributes?

Comment: var fileName is just a variable a came up with to show you how to concat it with alt and stick it in an array. In your example, trendy is an array, I don't know if that's where you want to store you alt values. In other words the questions you are asking really depend on what your requirements are and what way you want to go.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to store the alt values in the same array as the file names, but I'm not sure where I would put that information. Would you mind showing me how I would apply it to the first item in var trendy (trendy[0] = "files/set1/A1.jpg"; alt="black_dress")?

Comment: ok that's similar to my example: `trendy[0] = "files/set1/A1.jpg"  + '|' + "black_dress"`, or `trendy[0] = fileName  + '|' + alt`

Comment: I think I finally understood that part, and am now just having a bit of trouble getting the function to work :-) I think that I might be retrieving it or assigning 'var imgvalue' incorrectly (since function changeObjects() affects 2 arrays). Would you mind taking a look at the revised code in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/XjDuM/2/